# Need to fetch a particular substring from a delimited string in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string in SQL as

```
1|208080|"20170815|00:00:00"|"20160615|23:59:59
```

I just need to fetch the value `20160615` from the select statement in SQL

Comment: is it always after the second last `|`? Also which DBMS you are using?

Comment: Really bad idea to store data like that... Hope you're trying to fix it now!

Comment: @Nebi : Ya it is always after 2nd last, Software being used is Oracle SQL developer

Comment: Do you have a typo  in the unbalanced double-quotes?  Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression handles NULL elements should they exist in the list and grabs only the digits in the 5th pipe-delimited field (the double-quote looks like a typo but you never know).  It's flexible so you can get any field you want, just replace the '5' in the call with the field you want.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select '1|208080|"20170815|00:00:00"|"20160615|23:59:59'
     from dual
   )
   select regexp_substr(str, '(\d*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) field5
   from tbl;

FIELD5
--------
20160615

SQL>
```